# C++ linking to another project in visual studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I have a .cpp and a header in another project that I'd like to link to. I've added the header and placed the .lib file in the Linker/ Input/ Additional Dependencies but I get an unresolved external. From what I read this could be because the lib is part of a dll project. All I want to do is link to the obj of that class, but it doesn't appear to want to let me do that. I can link to another lib file in the same directory so it's not a path issue.

I could probably export the class as part of a DLL, but I don't want the worry of memory leaks as I would have to pass a pointer to the object, whereas if I link directly, I don't have to worry about it at all.

How's the best way to diagnose if I can link to the lib file.

Is there any particular reason VS2010 won't let me go directly to the obj file? This would seem to be the easiest option.

Thanks,
James

Comment: The library generated is only containing the _exported_ functions, variables and classes. So if the class in the file you want is not being exported it wont be in the library, and you have to add the actual source file to the other project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to link directly to the .obj file of the class, you will have to add the .cpp file of the class to your project. This, however easier it may seem, is not a solution to your problem, only a workaround. I cannot think of how to solve the problem, though.

Comment: Yes, I went with an Add Existing file to the project, as they're both part of an over arching solution. Thanks everyone with help for this!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new configuration where the project you link to is a static library instead of a DLL.

Add the project as a dependency of your new project and alter the configuration manager settings so it uses the static library configuration instead of the DLL configuration.

Comment: Yes I'd probably have to go down this route, but I can be fairly confident that the relative paths between my project and the other project shoudl be constant, so I went with the second solution. Again thanks for your suggestion.